# Different animations for content in flexslider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

Am using flexslider, and i need different style of animations for each of the contents in slides.My html code is like this

```
<li>
  <div style="background-image: url('/img/backgrounds/01.jpg'); height: 889px;" class="slide fullscreen" data-url="./img/backgrounds/01.jpg">
   <div style="height: 889px;" class="overlay fullscreen">
    <div style="margin-top: 332px;" class="container vertical-center">
             <h1 class="title">Land of Creativity</h1>
             <button class="welcome">Take a look</button>
    </div> 
     </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

and my js is like this

```
$(".home").flexslider({
        animation:"fade",
        animationLoop:true,
        animationSpeed:3000,
        easing:"easeOutBack",
        slideshow:true,
        pauseOnHover:false,
        controlNav:false,
        directionNav:false,


    });
```

I need different type of effects of each element in slide.
thank you for help.i found answer..
changed js like this

```
$(".home").flexslider({
        animation:"fade",
        animationLoop:true,
        animationSpeed:3000,
        easing:"easeOutBack",
        slideshow:true,
        pauseOnHover:false,
        controlNav:false,
        directionNav:false,
        start: function(slider){        
            $('#title1').delay(100).show().animate({opacity: 1, bottom:"0px"},'slow');
            $('#button1').delay(100).show().animate({opacity: 1, top:"0px"},'slow');

        },
        after: function(slider){
            if(slider.currentSlide == 1){
                $('#title2').delay(100).show().animate({opacity: 1, top:"-150px"},'slow');
                $('#button2').delay(100).show().animate({opacity: 1, bottom:"-90px"},'slow');
            }
            else if(slider.currentSlide == 2){
                $('#title3').delay(100).show().animate({opacity: 1, bottom:"0px", left:"0px"},'slow');
                $('#button3').delay(100).show().animate({opacity: 1, top:"0px"},'slow');
            }
            else if(slider.currentSlide == 3){
                $('#title4').delay(100).show().animate({opacity: 1, bottom:"0px", right:"0px"},'slow');
                $('#button4').delay(100).show().animate({opacity: 1, top:"0px"},'slow');
            }
            else{

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I would use a different slider as flexslider only has fade or slide effects.  [Here are some others](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2012/01/05/30-awesome-jquery-slide-show-plugins/)

Comment: thank you for your reply.i found answer :)